# what is the limit where we can define IN condition is bad or is it totally bad in mysql

Tags: mysql

There are plenty of articles and stackoverflow questions suggesting IN will slow the performance.

My question is, Can we define a limit for number of items do we have in the IN condition or totally do we have to remove IN condition regardless of how many items do you have in query. For example:

I have a table of 50000 records, I need to query with in condition for 20 id's(s_id) like below.

```
SELELCT s_id, date, start, end, slots, capacity where s_id IN (<20_id's>)
```

```
   CREATE TABLE `sso` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `start` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `end` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slots` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capacity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `s_id` (`s_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=317 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Which is the good option here

- In query with 20 ID's OR going for a temp table for them.

If  I have to retain the IN query since it is only 20(Assuming this count(20) is ok than creating a temp table)

Comment: Is there a problem?  20 items, even 50K items, is not impossible.

Comment: Rick, I am getting performance issue for a full function, I am trying to fix pieces of it

Comment: Does the table have 50K rows?  You are fetching only 20 rows?  Is there a performance problem?  How long does it take?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  What version of MySQL?  Are the ids quoted (versus simply numbers)?

Comment: It has 1 or 2 millions of rows, but the query which I asked here is part of a big PHP function which runs around 15 queries(excluding looped queries) through helper functions, we are in the optimization process and this is one of its piece.

Answer (score 0):

Usually 20 items in an `IN()` predicate is not a problem. In environments where I was responsible for database optimization, the problems started as the list got into hundreds or thousands.

But the real answer varies with each environment. You just need to test both strategies using your data on your server, and see which is best. Maybe even re-test for each query.

MySQL does have a relevant configuration option `range_optimizer_max_mem_size` . Read these sections of the manual:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_range_optimizer_max_mem_size
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-optimization-memory-use

The issue is that there's a small incremental amount of RAM used during query optimization, proportional to the length of the list of values. Not a problem for lists in the dozens, but it can use too much RAM if there are thousands. So the option constrains the amount of memory used to optimize each query. If the memory required would exceed that threshold, the optimizer says, "meh, I give up, this query has to just resort to a table-scan," which ruins the performance of your query.

This can cause a surprising degradation of performance if the list is generated by code or by another query. During development and testing, the list is probably going to be small, but over time, your production data grows to the point where eventually the list gets huge. So suddenly one day, the query that was using an index before, now uses a table-scan.

The developers insist they didn't change the code, and they're correct. It was the data that grew too large.

In that scenario, I set `range_optimizer_max_mem_size=0` which means no limit to the RAM usage. It was better to allow occasional high RAM usage than to let the query suddenly become unoptimized.